# MySql - SUM of workers per hour

Tags: php, mysql

With a little (lots) help from StackOverflow last year, I have a function that will show how many employees that are currently at work.

The code works fine - but now we have implemented night shifts and the original query only shows shifts that begin in the current date. People working nightshifts might check-in at 10PM and the leave at 8AM - in the current query, they don't show up, because startdate is the day before...

I have been trying to implement enddate in the query, but with no luck.

```
 teamslots
---------
id
startdate
starttime
enddate
endtime

 teamslot_schedule
-----------------
id
slotid (joins to is in teamslots)
userid

 shifthours
----------
thehour
```

This is the original query - I could really use some help that would make the query include employees, that are on a shift that begins the day before, but ends "today".

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(d.startdate + INTERVAL s.thehour HOUR, '%Y-%m-%d %H') AS date,
    COUNT(DISTINCT ts.userid) AS users
FROM
    shifthours s
JOIN
    (SELECT DISTINCT startdate FROM teamslots) d
LEFT JOIN
    teamslots t ON t.startdate = d.startdate AND
        s.thehour BETWEEN HOUR(t.starttime) AND HOUR(t.endtime)
LEFT JOIN
    teamslot_schedule ts ON ts.slotid = t.id
GROUP BY
    d.startdate,
    s.thehour
ORDER BY
    d.startdate + INTERVAL s.thehour HOUR;
```

Best regards,
Mark

Comment: Setup a SQL Fiddle and share with us what ou have tried so far.

Comment: How do you decide what day a shift falls on? Is it based on `enddate`?

Comment: Marcus : A shift has a startdate + starttime AND enddate + endtime - together they indicate the timespan a shift occupies.
eg. datestart "2014-07-01" starttime "22:00" enddate "2014-07-02" endtime "06:00" is a 8 hour shift that spans 2 dates.
This shift should count in the query for both "2014-07-01" AND "2014-07-02" but only in the correct hourslots.
"2014-07-01 22:00 +1"
"2014-07-01 23:00 +1"
"2014-07-02 00:00 +1"
"2014-07-02 01:00 +1"
"2014-07-02 02:00 +1"
"2014-07-02 03:00 +1"
"2014-07-02 04:00 +1"
"2014-07-02 05:00 +1"

Comment: The table "shifthours" holds only 24 rows from 0 - 23 used to join for each hour needed in the result.

Answer (score 0):

Use the MySQL CURDATE() function and subtract the appropriate interval for your shift length.